# Contesting Mojang's forced migration

Tags: software

Mojang is forcing their users to migrate their account with their Microsoft account. Personally, I don't agree with this migration and especially the way they are forcing it on their users: if you don't migrate, you will lose access to the game.

I have my reasons for not wanting to cooperate. For example, some people think it will even make the game [less secure](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/kd7fkl/the_javatomicrosoft_account_migration_is_going_to/). In any case, I demand to either have access to the game or to get a refund. The latter is not going to happen as long as it's up to Mojang, since my refund request does not meet their refund requirements.

Is there anything I can do about this? Can I force them to issue a refund?

Answer (score 7):

You agreed to terms of use when you started using Mojang, posted at https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/terms  and including:

> We may change these Account Terms from time to time, if we have reason
> to. For example, there might be changes to our games, our practices,
> or our legal obligations. We'll inform you of the change before it
> takes effect, either by posting a notice on our Website or some other
> reasonable way. If you use the Website or your account after the
> change, that means you agree to the changes. If you do not agree to
> the changes, stop using the Website. The changes will apply to your
> use of the Website when you next use it.

That means Microsoft and Mojang can make a decisions like moving/merging your account without asking your permission. Website and product Terms of Service agreements are legally binding contracts, and you agreed to them when you started using their services.

And refunds are part of the terms:

> RETURNS, REFUNDS AND CANCELLATION
> You or we may cancel your Mojang Account at any time or access to
> Minecraft.net, Mojang.com or any Mojang game titles using a Microsoft
> Account. When your account terminates or access is terminated, your rights
> under these Account Terms terminate.

They can cancel your account at any time and not give you a refund.

> *Can I force them to issue a refund?*

You can attempt to make your case in court, but a) you agreed to the contract, and 2) Microsoft has more money for lawyers than you do.

Comment: Agreeing to terms when playing the game, I get it. But does this mean they can basically do whatever they want? There must be limits. I mean, what's next. Are they going to restrict access to all players that refuse to provide a copy of their passport?

Comment: There are limits, they are limited to what is legal by law, aside from that they can request you send them pictures of you in bathing suits making snowmen on a winters day if they want.

Comment: They can request whatever they want. What surprises me is that they can apparently restrict access whenever I don't cooperate..

Comment: They are private businesses and they offer a service of a game. You do not have a right to use their services on your own terms; they make the terms, and if you agree to the terms, you can play. You also agreed that they can change the terms at any time. It's not a matter of life or death; it's simply a game.

Comment: You might have a legal case if you were losing something significant that was a major part of the game and no alternative was offered. But they are offering an alternative and you haven't demonstrated that it is much worse, so the contract allows it to be changed. It's highly unlikely that MS is significantly less secure than Mojang, who probably bought their security systems from a third party, maybe even MS. And some kind of 80s-style l33t hacker prejudice against Microsoft is unlikely to stand up in court.

Comment: @StuartF I'm not sure how true https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/11heasp/employee_claims_she_cant_use_microsoft_windows/ is but this would be the start for making a case for the alternative being "unreasonable." The game did have more open source elements to it which allowed for modification which Microsoft likes to lock down the ecosystem to prevent.

Comment: New update since Dec 18, 2023. There are 20 million users who didn't migrate their account to the new system and lost access to the game entirely. Microsoft is requiring them to buy the game at the new price in order to continue playing. 

This is clearly a significant loss of value for consumers with no alternatives offered. Is it now time for a class-action lawsuit? 
@StuartF

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your contract. [Here is the contract](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/terms) that I would have if I signed up right now. First, nothing in the contract indicates that you can remain MS-Free, indeed they say

> Note that some players access mojang.com and minecraft.net using a
> Microsoft Account. Terms of use with a Microsoft Account can be found
> here. Some countries may have restrictions on who and how a Microsoft
> Account can provision an Xbox Live Profile

The section on refunds says "If you can't use a game or a product because it doesn't work, let us know and we'll try to help you out", which is not a promise to give a refund, so they do not offer refunds. They say "We *might* also cancel or suspend a transaction if there has been an error", which is an option and not a commitment. They also say

> We may change these Account Terms from time to time, if we have reason
> to. For example, there might be changes to our games, our practices,
> or our legal obligations. We'll inform you of the change before it
> takes effect, either by posting a notice on our Website or some other
> reasonable way. If you use the Website or your account after the
> change, that means you agree to the changes. If you do not agree to
> the changes, stop using the Website. The changes will apply to your
> use of the Website when you next use it.

Hence the prospects for a refund based on them migrating to MS is extremely slim, at least give that version of the contract.

Comment: Alright, so even though it's kind of despicable (or at least I think so) to force such a migration on your community, there's nothing I can really do?

Comment: *"[...] there's nothing I can really do?"* You can stop using the site/games, they gave you that right to terminate your account.

Comment: I guess so, but I'll lose the ability to play the game and my 20 euros..

Answer (score 2):

Further to @user6726's answer, I figured I should thrown in a [link to the original "contract"](https://web.archive.org/web/20101221093644/http://www.minecraft.net/copyright.jsp) (to be specific, this is dated post-20/dec/2010 (as close as I could find) since that's when it went beta, and the beta is when most ppl bought minecraft. You can find an earlier version for the alpha if you got back in time.

Of note, nothing about that (or anywhere else I could find on the site) mentions anything about selling the "game as a service" or anything like that, and most definitely no mention of reserving the right to alter the terms in any way (though it *does* mention they ***unreserve*** the right to make an EULA later on). It quite clearly says you buy the game imo.

The earliest version of that page does however seem to mention something along the lines that you only bought the rights for up-to-and-including the final version? And the linked version that you buy the current state of the game, and that future updates are a bonus? (with a note about how it's so they reserve the right to abandon the software)